# Toggle text in HTML table using JS with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm using a datatable in Bootstrap to create a table which jinja2 will populate with values passed from Flask, example below:

| Name | URL |
| --- | --- |
| google | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) |
| reddit | [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) |

```
{% for site in results %}
<tr>
<td>{{ site['sitename'] }}</td>
<td>{{ site['url'] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I also have `site['new_url']` which is passed in results. I want to make the `site['url']` clickable and have that toggle between `site['url']` and `site['new_url']` when clicked.

I'd like to implement using JS if possible or if there is another easier way I'm up for that too!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A Js solution:

```py
{% for site in results %}
<tr>
<td>{{ site['sitename'] }}</td>
<td onclick="swapText()" id="target">{{ site['url'] }}</td>
</tr>
<script>
function swapText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("target");
  if (x.innerHTML === "{{ site['url'] }}") {
    x.innerHTML = "{{ site['new_url'] }}";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "{{ site['url'] }}";
  }
}
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This somewhat works, however, it seems that "target" is set to the first value only, so whenever I click on any cell it only changes the first row value.

Comment: @BrianWarehime i could not understand your question fully, and still cannot, so i've given you a basic demo